# Detect if user is scrolling dataGridView scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am updating a `dataGridView` with a new DataTable using

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

However, I don't want to do this when a user is scrolling the dataGridView. How do I check if the scrollbar is being scrolled or completed scrolling (ie dragging rather than clicking)?

I've had a look at the Scroll event but it only seems to trigger when the scrollbar is first clicked and not completed. A Google search doesn't seem to bring up much specific to this either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this in the past by sub-classing the DataGridView class, and using that instead of the DataGridView.

```
public class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView
{
    public bool IsUserScrolling { get; private set; }

    private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114;
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
    private const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 8;

    public event EventHandler UserScrollComplete;

    protected virtual void OnUserScrollComplete()
    {
        EventHandler handler = UserScrollComplete;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787575(v=vs.85).aspx
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577(v=vs.85).aspx
        if ((m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL) ||
            (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL))
        {

            short loword = (short)(m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF);

            if (loword == SB_ENDSCROLL)
            {
                IsUserScrolling = false;

                OnUserScrollComplete();
            }
            else
            {
                IsUserScrolling = true;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```